Why is the cost for a Postgres query is so high if sequential scans are disabled?
Consider the following query:
select distinct pnumber
from project
where pnumber in
(select pnumber
 from project, department d, employee e
 where e.dno=d.dnumber
 and
 d.mgr_snn=ssn 
 and 
 e.lname='employee1' and project.pnumber = 2 )
or
pnumber in
(select pno
 from works_on, employee
 where essn=ssn and lname='employee1' );

I wanted to test using brin indicies so I dropped the primary key constraints on all my tables and added the following indicies:
CREATE INDEX idx_brin_pnumber ON project USING brin(pnumber);
CREATE INDEX idx_brin_ssn ON project USING brin(ssn);
CREATE INDEX idx_brin_dnumber ON project USING brin(dnumber);
CREATE INDEX idx_brin_essn ON project USING brin(essn);

and I will attach the output query plan below

I used to think that the reason was due to the seqScans necesssary during the join, but then when I run the same query without any indicies and enable seqscan, it does it in a much lower cost. So what is the reason for this?

That's just the way PostgreSQL implements enable_seqscan=off.
You can never completely disable sequential scans, because sometimes that is the only access method for a table. With enable_seqscan disabled, PostgreSQL just adds a cost of 10000000000 to each sequential scan. That way, the optimizer will always prefer plans that avoid a sequential scan, if there are any.

That was insightful, if you have a resource or sth I can read more about stuff like that (concerning flags and indicies) it would be really helpful.

The documentation is very good.
